# Remove strings begining with 'AUTO_INCREMENT=' in 2 files

Tags: ruby, string, import

I am trying to create a ruby script that loads 2 .sql files and removes all strings that begin with 'AUTO_INCREMENT='
There are multiple occurrences of this in my .sql files and all I want is them to be removed from both files.
Thanks for any help or input as I am new to ruby and decided to give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the right regexp (the one below might not be the most correct given the syntax), and the answer given [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274605/ruby-search-file-text-for-a-pattern-and-replace-it-with-a-given-value/1274631#1274631) to a similar question, it is rather straightforward to put a script together:

```
file_names = ['file1.sql', 'file2.sql']

file_names.each do |file_name|
  text = File.read(file_name)
  File.open(file_name, 'wb') do 
    |file| 
    file.write(text.gsub(/\s*AUTO_INCREMENT\s*(\=\s*[0-9]+)?/, "")) 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Regex for this? If you want to remove the whole line, you could simply match ^AUTO_INCREMENT=.+$ and replace it with an empty string. That pattern should match an entire line beginning with AUTO_INCREMENT.

[Here's a good site to learn Regex if you aren't familiar with it:](http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html)

Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on [IO, String, Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/) for more details on methods you can use.

Here's how you might read, modify, and save the contents of one file:

```
# Opens a file for reading.
file = File.open("file1.txt")

# Reads all the contents into the string 'contents'.
contents = file.read
file.close

# Splits contents into an array of strings, one for each line.
lines = contents.split("\n")

# Delete any lines that start with AUTO_INCREMENT=
lines.reject! { |line| line =~ /^AUTO_INCREMENT=/ }

# Join the lines together into one string again.
new_contents = lines.join("\n")

# Open file for writing.
file = File.open("file1.txt", "w")

# Save new contents.
file.write(new_contents)
file.close
```