# Ruby File operation

Tags: ruby

I have a requirement like I have a file which will be having rows like

```
424: Josh
1273: Sara Keith
141: Shefali
990: Lang
849: Broc Benedict
566: Victoria 
283: Karla Mateos
```

(Id and Name). When I get a name in params I should open and remove the matching line.Is it possible to open file and grep matching line and remove it in a simple way?

Comment: Read up on Ruby file i/o. Heres one tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/ruby-for-newbies-working-with-directories-and-files/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `File` class in rub which helps you in file operations.
Simlar problem is answered here.

[How to search file text for a pattern and replace it with a given value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274605/ruby-search-file-text-for-a-pattern-and-replace-it-with-a-given-value)

Comment: I want to remove that line if match happens..