# Replace a string in txt file with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby. I am trying to save a change within same text file using Ruby. How do I approach this?

This is what I tried:

```
f = File.open("D:/test.txt", "r")
oldcolor = "white"
newcolor = "black"
f.each_line do |line|
  line.sub(oldcolor,newcolor)
  puts line
end
f.close
```

Any suggestions how to use variables in `sub` instead of regex or may be any other method to replace "white" to "black" ?

Comment: try `puts line.sub(oldcolor,newcolor)`

Comment: That worked!! . Now I am trying to save the change within same file as well

Comment: You can't change a file in-place. Instead, you have to read it from disk into memory, make the changes and write it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that @ShaneQful's response is good because it uses your code but you can as he stated make this far easier with

```
file_name = "D:/test.txt"
old_color = "white"
new_color = "black"
File.write(file_name,File.open(file_name,&:read).gsub(old_color,new_color))
```

What this does is it opens `file_name` reads it out into a string. Replaces (`#gsub`) all the instances of `old_color` with `new_color` and then writes it back to `file_name`.

Simple, easy, clean and concise.

**Update**

Benchmarking of `File#read`, `File.open(file_name,&:read)`, and `File.open with block read into a string and then written back to file_name`(as in ShaneQful's example)

This was benchmarked against Jack London's White Fang which contains ~75,000 words and 645 instances of the word `white`

```
#Benchmark
Rehearsal --------------------------------------------------------
File#read              0.375000   0.484000   0.859000 (  1.462000)
File.open(&:read)      0.437000   0.530000   0.967000 (  1.480000)
File.open with block   1.404000   0.359000   1.763000 (  2.150000)
----------------------------------------------- total: 3.589000sec

                           user     system      total        real
File#read              0.452000   0.499000   0.951000 (  1.401000)
File.open(&:read)      0.483000   0.421000   0.904000 (  1.445000)
File.open with block   1.529000   0.328000   1.857000 (  2.120000)
#Fruity
Running each test 2 times. Test will take about 3 minutes.
File.open(&:read) is similar to File#read
File#read is faster than File.open with block by 50.0% ± 10.0%
```

It seems `File#read` and `File.open(file_name,&:read)` trade hands back and forth as to the speed of implementation but utilizing a true block to handle the same operation is always much slower for this type of thing.

Synopsis for easy procedures like this use `read` or `#open(file_name,&:read)` (`Symbol#to_proc`). If you need to perform elaborate changes that may take multiple lines or conditional options then I would use a block

Comment: **I am new to ruby.** And you used &:read?  I'm old to ruby, and I wouldn't write that perlish code.  There are also other advantages to using blocks when opening files.

Comment: @7stud I chose to use Symbol#to_proc because the implementation is cleaner and has better performance than the block in this case. Please remember the OP also stated "...or may be any other method to replace 'white' to 'black' ?"

Comment: Is there any advantage to `File.open(name,&:read)` over `File.read(name)` ?

Comment: @FrederickCheung not sure. I will benchmark all three later on today and post results.

Comment: @FrederickCheung benchmarking added. It seems `File#read` vs `File.open(file_name, &:read)` have almost no difference and they trade back and forth as to which method is faster.

Comment: @7stud I have added benchmarking to show why I chose not to use a block for such a simple procedure.

Comment: Using `read` makes the code unscalable as the script will crawl when memory is full. Instead, use line-by-line I/O which remains constant and is scalable. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25189286/128421

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is :

```
f = File.open("D:/test.txt", "r")
oldcolor = "white"
newcolor = "black"
newfile_str = ""
f.each_line do |line|
  newfile_str += line.sub(oldcolor,newcolor)
end
f.close
File.open("D:/test.txt", "w") {|file| file.puts newfile_str}
```

There are easier ways of doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274605/ruby-search-file-text-for-a-pattern-and-replace-it-with-a-given-value) but I wanted to use your own code to make it easier for you to understand.

Explanation:
I'm storing the modified lines in a string and then writing it to the file.

Comment: Don't aggregate the lines to be written into a string. That creates a potential problem if the program runs out of memory. Instead of storing the strings, immediately write them out. That keeps as much available memory and doesn't impact I/O speed. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25189286/128421

Answer (score 1):

> I am new to ruby. I am trying to save a change within same text file
>   using ruby.

For all practical purposes, you can't, and you really don't want to anyway--ever.  Instead, write to a new file, delete the old file, rename the new file to old file name.