# Ruby: Search file text for a pattern and replace 'part of' it with a given value?

Tags: ruby, regex, file-io

This is a follow-up question to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274605/ruby-search-file-text-for-a-pattern-and-replace-it-with-a-given-value).

I am new to Ruby and want to create a script that will search a file for a pattern. However, I want to only replace part of it, i.e. remove all `http://` patterns matches but *only* when they are followed by a valid url.

Answer (score 1):

If "valid url" means that the string is parseable as an URL, then you might try using `URI.parse`. For example:

```
require 'uri'
IO.readlines(input_file).each do |line|
  line.gsub(%r;(https?://\S+);) do |url|
    URI.parse(url) && '' rescue url
  end
end
```

However, the `URI` module is very lax. You'll find strings like `not-an-uri` are considered valid "generic" URIs.

You might want to check whether the captured URL can be fetched and returns a successful HTTP status. That is significantly more resource intensive, so operating over a large input file would be very slow. It also could be considered a security risk.

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

def valid_url?(url)
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  Net::HTTP.get_response(uri).is_a? Net::HTTPSuccess
rescue
 return false
end

IO.readlines(input_file).each do |line|
  line.gsub(%r;(https?://\S+);) do |url|
    valid_url?(url) ? '' : url
  end
end
```