# RegEx for adding "\n\n" " 2 new line" when I found "\n"

Tags: regex, ruby, regex-greedy

My scenario is:

```
alleyway\n behind the venue\n. The young agent never\n\n.
```

I have a paragraph. And I want to add \n only when I find \n.
ex. in above sentence I want "venue\n\n".

Comment: What is your expected result for the given paragraph?

Comment: Here is an exact andwer using gsub http://stackoverflow.com/a/1274631/461887